# Select Top N rows for Employees in a SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I would like to select the TOP 2 activities carried out by all employees from an Employees table "Emp" which has a timestamp column.

The regular "Select Top 2 * from Emp...." will only fetch the top two activities from the whole table. However what i really want is to get the top 2 activities for each emplyee 'EmpName'

Here's the table
*Sorry it's not properly formatted

```
EmpName     | Activities          |  Date      
------------|---------------------|----------------
Linda       |   Cleaning          |    21/6/2011
Joe         |   Washing           |    22/6/2011  
Joe         |   Painting          |    18/5/2011  
Samson      |   Cleaning          |    22/5/2011  
Samson      |   Painting          |    25/4/2011  
Joe         |   Cleaning          |    07/4/2011  
Linda       |   Painting          |    16/5/2011  
Samson      |   Washing           |    13/7/2011  
Dave        |   Cleaning          |    28/5/2011  
Linda       |   Washing           |    09/6/2011  
Joe         |   Washing           |    23/5/2011  
Linda       |   Painting          |    17/5/2011  
Samson      |   Cleaning          |    19/3/2011  
Dave        |   Washing           |    24/5/2011
```

Comment: Why would `select TOP 2` not work?  You should be able to just `order by` and get your answer.  Like `SELECT TOP 2 Activity, count(*) as count group by activity order by count(*) desc`

Comment: @KrisGruttemeyer You've been here a while now Kris. Don't you know we're supposed to guess table structure and the actual problem?

Comment: HA! Sorry, forgot about that.  Not enough coffee yet.

Comment: @Cole Please post the table structure, result set you'd like from the query and also why `SELECT TOP 2` will not work...

Comment: @Cole - as Mark said, without providing details there is no way you can expect any answer, much less a good answer.

Comment: Sorry about that. I had issues structuring the table and not making it appear gibberish in stack exchange is why i had it removed. I'll try to include it again

Comment: You can post gibberish. Odds are that one of us can format it if need be.

Comment: The post has been edited with more details now. I hope that helps. Thanks

Comment: When you say "top 2" activities, do you mean by most recent time, or by the most frequently performed like Kris assumed in the first comment?

Comment: "Top 2" here refers to the two most recent activities for each employee and not frequency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you found out, using `TOP` doesn't work here, because that applies to the entire result set, whereas you want the top N rows from each grouping.

One way to do this is by using a ranking function; I've used [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) in this example (note: not syntax checked):

```
SELECT
    a.EmpName,
    a.Activities,
    a.Date
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            EmpName,
            Activities,
            Date,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EmpName ORDER BY Date DESC) AS ActivityRank
            FROM Employees
    ) a
    WHERE a.ActivityRank <= 2 /* This is the top N for each employee */
    ORDER BY
        a.EmpName,
        a.Date DESC;
```

Comment: Nice!! Thanks Jon. This seemed to do the trick

Comment: I've noticed the result skips dates For example the result brings employees activities in April and June and would leave out those activities in May where available.
I'll edit it and revert with an update once done.

Comment: @Cole: My query assumes that the table schema is strongly typed and that there's no "junk" data in the table. In other words, if that `Date` column is actually using a string type (i.e., `char` or `varchar`), then the DD/MM/YYYY format won't sort correctly. Without seeing the schema, I cannot give a better answer than what's already there.

Comment: Thats precisely what happened. I went through the table and noticed the date column was has "junk" data in it and is not properly formatted.
Once again thanks for the swift response

Comment: @Cole: Okay; you're welcome.